# Convert an array of dictionaries into a set Swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary, set, swift4

I have an array of dictionaries (`[[Double:Double]]`) which I want to convert into a `Set` of dictionaries. My goal is to use the `.symmetricDifference` to find the differences between two arrays (both are of type `[[Double:Double]]`). How can I do this?

I found [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-find-the-difference-between-two-arrays) on hackingwithswift.com and tried to use it but I am getting this error:

> Type '[[Double : Double]]' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'

I have also tried this code...

```
let array1:[[Double:Double]] = [[4.5:3.678], [6.7:9.2867], [7.3: 8.7564]]
let array2:[[Double:Double]] = [[4.5:3.678], [6.7:9.2867]]

let array3 = Set<[[Double:Double]]>(array1).symmetricDifference(Set(array2)) //On this line I get the error above.
```

Comment: Update your question with your actual, relevant code.

Comment: I have updated my question. @rmaddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a Set of `[[Double:Double]]`. You want a Set of `[Double:Double]`, because those are the objects *in* the array and you want them to be the objects *in* the Set.

Thus the right thing will happen if you simply say

```
let array1:[[Double:Double]] = [[4.5:3.678], [6.7:9.2867], [7.3: 8.7564]]
let set1 = Set(array1)
```

and so on.

This *might* require you to update to a newer version of Swift. It works in Swift 4.2.

Comment: FYI - I put this into a playground in Xcode 9.4 (Swift 4.1.2) and got a bunch of errors.

Comment: I am getting errors with this code as well, while using swift 4.1. I will try updating swift and see what happens. If anyone has another idea that works in swift 4.1, I am open.

Comment: Yeah, dictionaries are not hashable without conditional conformance, a 4.2 feature.